# How do I register polygons as traces in Altium?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, trace

I've used the **Place>Soild Region** command to create polygon traces for my board. However when I highlight the traces by hovering over and pressing shift. The Net is connected but the highlight does not include the polygon I made. I think I'm doing polygons in the wrong way. If I do **Place>Fill**I can only make rectangles but it does highlight all the correct regions.

Here is an example of Place>Soild Region not being a part of the highlighted trace connections.

[image]

Comment: Can you just edit the polygon and assign your desired net to it?

Answer (score 1):

Try Place -> Polygon, not Place -> Solid Region

The polygon dialog comes up and you can give it a net.

Comment: You can also edit the net in the properties window.